# How to preserve tabs in Github for Makefiles

Tags: c, git, makefile

Github automatically converts tabs to multiple spaces. So, every time I create a `Makefile` in Github, I need to clone the repository in my Linux box and edit th `Makefile` using `vim` and then `push` the changes back to my Github repository to avoid the following error while executing `make install|clean`:

`Makefile:  : *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.`

Is there an elegant way to preserve tabs in Github website especially for `Makefiles`?

Comment: Apparently it's not a GitHub whom to blame. Otherwise imagine the size of the issue!

Comment: @0andriy: Ah, ugly truth! You won't have this issue if you `commit` and `push` from the terminal at least using `vim` in my case.

Comment: You mean you use the *Github editor*

Answer (score 3):

You can write a smudge/clean filters to "clean" up the file every commit/checkout of files.
The script will replace any spaces/tabs with the desired format.

The smudge/clean are filters which are runs whenever you commit file (clean) and checkout file to a working directory (smudge).

---

### ***`Smudge / clean`***

Read all about it and to set it up here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

> It turns out that you can write your own filters for doing substitutions in files on **commit/checkout**.
>
> These are called `clean` and `smudge` filters.
>
> In the `.gitattributes` file, you can set a filter for particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re checked out (“smudge”) and just before they’re staged (“clean”).
>
> These filters can be set to do all sorts of fun things.

[image]