# Prevent large text file from being added to commit when using GitHub

Tags: bash, git, unity-game-engine, github, git-lfs

We want to prevent:

- Very large text files (> 50MB per file) from being committed to `git` instead of `git-lfs`, as they inflate git history.
- Problem is, 99% of them are < 1MB, and should be committed for better diffing.
- The reason of variance in size: these are YAML files, they support binary serialization via base64 encoding.
- The reason we can't reliably prevent binary serialization: this is a Unity project, binary serialization is needed for various reasons.

Given:

- GitHub hosting's lack of pre-receive hook support.
- git-lfs lack of file size attribute support.

Questions:

1. How can we reliably prevent large files from being added to commit?
2. Can this be done through a config file in repo so all users follow this rule gracefully?
3. If not, can this be done by bash command aliasing so trusted users can see a warning message when they accidentally `git add` a large file and it's not processed by `git-lfs`?

(Our environment is macOS. I have looked at many solutions and so far none satisfy our needs)

Comment: [How to limit file size on commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39576257/3776858)

Comment: Can you include (at least some of) the solutions you've looked at and discarded? I'm not especially well-versed in git hooks, but this sounds like something a `pre-commit` hook could handle to me.

Comment: @Cyrus I didn't read that one, thx, but I need to test if it includes the possibility of a file that would be tracked by git-lfs. Yes it will prevent large file, but does git-lfs kicks in before pre-commit, that's the question.

Comment: @solarshado I will add some links later, but I am assuming pre-commit doesn't consider git-lfs, but I really don't know enough about git-lfs to say one way or another.

Comment: I'm not familiar with git-lfs either, but based on [its home page](https://git-lfs.github.com/), it looks like it "Just Works:tm:". Skimming over some of the [docs](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tree/master/docs/man), it sounds like it uses a pre-push hook for some (most?) of its magic.

Answer (score 8):

Alright, with helps from CodeWizard and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963854/list-files-not-tracked-by-git-lfs), I managed to create a good guide myself:

First, setup your repo `core.hooksPath` with:

```
git config core.hooksPath .githooks
```

Second, create this `pre-commit` file inside `.githooks` folder, so it can be tracked ([gist link](https://gist.github.com/bitinn/834756d57f3d47df97937aab68162ae6)), then remember to give it execution permission with `chmod +x`.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
# Called by "git commit" with no arguments. The hook should
# exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message if
# it wants to stop the commit.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-commit".

# Redirect output to stderr.
exec 1>&2

FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_KB=1024
CURRENT_DIR="$(pwd)"
COLOR='\033[01;33m'
NOCOLOR='\033[0m'
HAS_ERROR=""
COUNTER=0

# generate file extension filter from gitattributes for git-lfs tracked files
filter=$(cat .gitattributes | grep filter=lfs | awk '{printf "-e .%s$ ", $1}')

# before git commit, check non git-lfs tracked files to limit size
files=$(git diff --cached --name-only | sort | uniq | grep -v $filter)
while read -r file; do
    if [ "$file" = "" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    file_path=$CURRENT_DIR/$file
    file_size=$(ls -l "$file_path" | awk '{print $5}')
    file_size_kb=$((file_size / 1024))
    if [ "$file_size_kb" -ge "$FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_KB" ]; then
        echo "${COLOR}${file}${NOCOLOR} has size ${file_size_kb}KB, over commit limit ${FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_KB}KB."
        HAS_ERROR="YES"
        ((COUNTER++))
    fi
done <<< "$files"

# exit with error if any non-lfs tracked files are over file size limit
if [ "$HAS_ERROR" != "" ]; then
    echo "$COUNTER files are larger than permitted, please fix them before commit" >&2
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Now, assuming you got both `.gitattributes` and `git-lfs` setup properly, this pre-commit hook will run when you try to `git commit` and make sure all staged files not tracked by git-lfs (as specified in your `.gitattributes`), will satisfy the specified file size limit.

Any new users of your repo will need to setup `core.hooksPath` themselves, but beyond that, *things should just work*.

Hope this helps other Unity developers fighting with growing git repo size!

Comment: `man git-config` says about `core.hooksPath` :
`This configuration variable is useful in cases where you’d like to centrally configure your Git hooks instead of configuring them on a per-repository basis`. Your command `git config core.hooksPath .githooks` returns `fatal: not in a git directory` when I run it from `$HOME`, shall I need to use the `--global` option if I want the hooks to be usable by every projects on my machine ?

Comment: Kind of the same question asked here with a very nice answer imo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578014/1582649

Answer (score 3):

> - How can we reliably prevent large files from being added to commit?
> - Can this be done through a config file in the repo so all users follow this rule gracefully?
>     Since GitHub doesn't support server-side hooks you can use client-side hooks. As you probably aware, those hooks can be passed and be disabled with no problem, but still, this is a good way to do it.

---

## `core.hooksPath`

Git **v2.9** added the ability to set the client hooks on remote folder. Prior to that, the hooks must have been placed inside the `.git` folder.

This will allow you to write scripts and put them anywhere. I assume you know what hooks are but if not feel free to ask.

---

#### How to do it?

Usually, you place the hooks inside your repo (or any other common folder).

```
# set the hooks path. for git config, the default location is --local
# so this configuration is locally per project
git config core.hooksPath .githooks
```

Comment: very nice, I will check it out and report back

Comment: Alright, so this works, but the hook took me a while (code from other SO has issues handling whitespace in path), so I made mine, feel free to append them for a more complete answer: https://gist.github.com/bitinn/834756d57f3d47df97937aab68162ae6

Comment: Cool, glad to help

Comment: sorry I speak a bit too soon, this doesn't seem to work with git-lfs yet, as in, it isn't smart enough to skip file that can be handled by git-lfs (say a PNG file, which is likely over 1MB, but can be committed because lfs could handle it)

Comment: You can do it using smudge-clean scripts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773264/how-to-preserve-tabs-in-github-for-makefiles/41773892#41773892

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184953/discussion-between-bitinn-and-codewizard).