# How to prevent my local git to accept large files?

Tags: git, github

How can configure my local git repository to prevent it to accept large files, which will later generate a error when trying to push to GitHub?

I've recently had a problem with a large file I've, by mistake, added to my local git repository. I've managed to fix it, by editing the commits in my local git and removing the file, through a series of git commands I don't remember right now. What I know it took a big slice of my time.

I'd like to prevent it to happen again, by somehow putting a block in my **local** git repository when I try to add a large file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gitignore by file size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035779/gitignore-by-file-size)

Comment: I guess that you didn't find any results as you didn't type the word **ignore** in your search box. This is a problem with command line interfaces in general: you need to know the term to look for help, but you need the help to find the term.

Comment: Note that [this answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824800/589259) automates the process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578014/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/53692461/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+prevent+adding+large+files

Comment: @MaartenBodewes your suggestion does not helps me, because it only provides way to add all files currently in my files that are over 1g to .gitignore.  I'd like something more permanent, wich wouldn't require me to run a .bat before every commit.

Comment: Sorry @MaartenBodewes, now I've seen your last message. It might ideed solve my problem, I'll take a look.

Comment: My bad as well, I posted the dupe link, and then I asked myself if this would automate it, and then I found that indeed the answer was there. So, yeah, I got lucky there as well. Anyway, I hope it solves your problem, do let us know!