Force git to ignore or truncate large files when pushing to remote
I need to "mirror" a number of git repositories hosted on hostA in repositories on hostB. I have read-only access to the repositories on hostA and own the repositories on hostB, but I do not have administrative rights on hostB.
I wrote "mirror" in quotes, because I only need to track the main branch and tags thereon. The only requirement is that at every tagged commit on the main branch, the code bases on hostA and hostB match.
A straightforward way to do this with an intermediate jump (my computer) is:
git clone hostA:repo1.git
cd repo1
git remote add hostB:repo1.git

and then for every time I want to sync:
git pull hostA main
git push hostB main
git push --tags hostB main

This works fine most of the time, except there are some repositories that have large binary files in them, and hostB has a maximum file size limit, while hostA does not. hostB does have git LFS, while hostA does not. So I cannot push these repositories to hostB without taking some action to exclude the large files. In fact: there is a hook on the hostB that blocks me pushing.
Some possible solution paths I have identified:

Remove the large files from the repositories on hostA: this obviously would be the right thing (TM) to do, but for various reasons beyond the scope of this question this is just not going to happen.
Use git LFS: this would require to untrack the large files and add them to git LFS. This means making local changes before pushing to hostB, after which I'm no longer to pull from hostA without conflict.
Use git filter-repo to remove the large binary files: this mostly preserves the history (the large files are not of interest for me), but obviously this is a nuclear option. As it rewrites the history entirely, I also no longer pull from hostA (I think - I might be doing it wrong...).

I'm currently using option (2) and every time I want to sync I clone a fresh copy, filter it, and force push to hostB, but this is far from ideal.
Ideally, I'm looking for a way to truncate the binary files to zero bytes size and have git ignore that file both when pulling from hostA (i.e., git does not see a conflict) and pushing the empty file to hostB without complaining.
To be clear: I don't want my pushing to hostB to be blocked by e.g. a pre-commit hook telling me the file is too big. I already know the file is too big. I want to push the entire history with exclusion of the offending file (I understand that that means that I'm corrupting the history with that, because I'm pushing an "untrue" commit with a modified file).
I'm not sure if this is at all possible, so I'm open to other solutions also. The sync is about once a month only, so the solution may be a bit involved.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578014/7976758 Use a pre-commit hook that prevents committing large files https://stackoverflow.com/a/53692461/7976758 https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pre-commit+hook+large+files

@phd I still want to be able to push. If I remove the file I have diverging histories.

Git doesn't push files. Git doesn't push commits. Git push chains of commits. So no, you cannot truncate files during push, you need to rewrite commits to be pushed. To avoid force-pushing rewrite only not yet pushed commits. The bottom line is: either you rewrite (part of) history and push or you push as is; these are the only alternatives you have.

@phd Would it be possible to rewrite only the commit where the large file was added? So I pull history A->B->C from hostA with in commit B the offending file added. I locally modify commit B to BB, removing/truncating the large file, and then push A->BB->C to hostB. Or would that also give me an issue next time I do "pull" from hostA?

No, you cannot rewrite non-tip commit — all commits from the tip to the offending commit will be rewritten and you will need git push --force. You can rewrite the tip commit but if it's on the server already you still need force-push. Only not yet pushed commits can be safely rewritten and pushed.

In my opinion this not possible, because you cannot change on the fly the content you are going to push (mirror).
You can only avoid to push files larger than a specified size for example using a git hook like the following:
#!/bin/bash

# Located in .git/hooks/pre-push

MAX_SIZE=1024

human_size() {
    awk -v sum=$1 'BEGIN {
        hum[1024^3]="GB";hum[1024^2]="MB";hum[1024]="KB";
        for (x=1024^3; x>=1024; x/=1024) {
            if (sum>=x) { printf "%.2f %s\n", sum/x, hum[x]; break }
        }
    }'
}

files_to_push=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM)

for file in $files_to_push; do
    
    if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    size=$(du -k "$file" | cut -f1)
    if [ $size -gt $MAX_SIZE ]; then
        echo "Error: File $file is larger than the allowed size of $(human_size $((MAX_SIZE * 1024)))."
        exit 1
    fi
done

# If we're here, all files are of an allowed size
exit 0

I think the only real solution is to filter and clean your source repo by BFG Repo-Cleaner.

This gives an error when the file is too big and thus prevents me to push to hostB.  I still want to be able to push. If I remove the file I have diverging histories.

Please, read carefullly my post. I wrote that this script BLOCKS the push, and for that reason I ended suggesting you to clean your source repo by BFG.

I understand what you wrote, but I wrote in my post that cleaning the source repo is not an option, unfortunately, even though I fully agree that would be the right thing to do.

I am sorry, but as I stated in my answer, what you need is not possible because you cannot change what the push command is sending remotely.

Fair enough, "no" is also an answer
